# how to add custom permissions and role based in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

1. models.py    ===============      from django.contrib.auth.models
   import AbstractUser from django.db import models

   ```
      # Create your models here. class User(AbstractUser):    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
   ```

   is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)    is_staff =
   models.BooleanField(default=False)    is_admin =
   models.BooleanField(default=False)    is_teacher =
   models.BooleanField(default=False)    is_student =
   models.BooleanField(default=False)

   ```
      class Admin(models.Model):    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   ```

   related_name="admin_account")

   ```
      def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username

      class Teacher(models.Model):    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   ```

   related_name="teacher_account")
   def **str**(self):
   return self.user.username

   ```
      class Student(models.Model):    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   ```

   related_name="student_account")
   def **str**(self):
   return self.user.username

Comment: Check this out [DRF permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a class that inherits BasePermission and you can give you logic has_permission method.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsTeacher(BasePermission): # you class name
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user.student and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar before having students and teachers,but for me what I did was make the student and teacher model inherit from User class.
With that in mind,my permission classes looked like this:

```
class IsStudent(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.student and request.user.is_authenticated
```